# VirtualBox resolution/guest additions

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, resolution, guest-additions

I saw this question come up quite a lot, however none of the posts, threads etc. I found did not help me to solved my problem.

Let me explain my situation. As a host OS for my VB I am using Windows 10 64-bit and I am running Windows 7 64-bit as a guest. Win7 in VB runs fine, just for one think. I can't set resolution to 1920x1080 (however I managed set it to 1920x1200 and higher), max resolution of my monitor.

After very quick research I figured out that somethink called "guest additions" exists, so I installed it.

- Devices -> insert guest additions CD image...

Installation began and finished sucessfully (at least it looked like it did) and I rebooted the guest OS. But nothing changed. "Seamless mode" and "Auto-resize Guest Display" in View menu are still greyed out and if I fiddle with the window size as much as I want, the guest resolution doesn't adjust and stays static.

I tried install Guest Additions twice then reinstall it etc. I read thru handfull of threads and posts about this/similar topic but I didn't find any answer and I am basically clueless now. Maybe I am disregarding some basic think as usually?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem. Win 10 host - Win 7 guest. I have had 1400*1050 max resolution on both Full HD display.

My steps:

1. Reinstall: vbox 5.1.4 to vbox 5.1.2
2. Run command in virtualbox program folder: "VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any"
3. Direkt download on host vbox guest additions 5.0.16 (other build don't resolve the problem)
4. Mount to the client the VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.16.iso.
5. Start client
6. Install the guest additions from the mount.
7. Restart client
8. Set desktop integration and/or full hd resolution on client.
9. Kill vboxtray application process in client (high processor usage, killed the performance) Be patient!
10. Rename VBoxTray.exe in client, 2 places. (program files\oracle\virtualbox guest additions and windows\system32 folder)
11. Reboot client.

Result: I can use full hd resolution. The shared clipboard doesn't operate for me, but I can live with feature.